# Fedora 16 desktop missing workspaces, Applications and Desktop menus at top of window

Tags: fedora, gnome

My last system was Fedora 12, and I don't recall doing anything special to get

Applications Places Desktop

at the top and having multiple workspaces (also switchable at the top).  I can't find any of this in my new Fedora 16 installation - what am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the fact the Fedora has moved from GNOME 2.x to Gnome 3... and that most users have moved on to Xfce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am doing now is using Activities and putting them on the bar at the top, and using KDE - this seems to do what I need.  What I didn't like about Gnome 3 was the lack of minimize button at the top right of the window - I didn't want minimizing to be a two step activity.  I also wanted activity (workspace) switching to be a one click activity.

But there are also multiple virtual desktops which can be set in Settings->System Settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between multiple workspaces with `ctrl+alt+up` / `ctrl+alt+down`. To the retrieve the application you should use `super` key (or `windows` key) and write the name of wanted application or place